# daterangepicker is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got an error when trying to create daterangepicker, I did exactly as instructed on https://www.daterangepicker.com, but it didn't work. What this erro? How to fix this erro? I have just started learning js recently, please can you give me a detailed guide. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<link href="static/html/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/html/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/html/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/html/css/colors/default.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="date_times"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
        endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
        }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    function submitDate() {
        document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>
<style>
    div.set_height {
    height: 100px;
    }
</style>   
</head> 
<body class="fix-header">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-7 white-box set_height">
            <h3 class="box-title">Historical Table</h3>
            <p class="text-muted"> Data will be saved every 30 minutes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 white-box set_height">
            <form id="frm1" method=POST action="{{ url_for('get_history') }}">
                <h3 class="box-title"> Filter :
                    <input type="text" placeholder="M/D/Y H:m - M/D/Y H:m" name="date_times"/>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="submitDate()" style=background-color:#e7e7e7;color:blue;>Submit</button>
                </h3>
            </form>
            <p class="text-muted">Select date and time</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer text-center"> © Dashboard Pepple Counting </footer>

<script src="static/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/html/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/html/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="static/html/js/waves.js"></script>
<script src="static/html/js/custom.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add your code to question

Comment: Oh sorry,  I have added the code

Comment: What errors are you getting in browser console? I can see you have added `jquery.min.js` two times in your code..

Comment: i got it: "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/historical:148:65)
    at j (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js:2:30313) undefined"

Comment: Is your page being served via http or https? If the latter, then you'll need to change all references to `<script src="http://...">` to https.

Comment: Oh, I have fixed the error, thanks.

Comment: What was the error and how did you fix it?